# Passing a username and password with every WCF request

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I have a table with all usernames and their hashed passwords that are allowed to access a WCF service.

Is there a problem with using message level security and pass the username and password with each request as part of the encrypted body?

Why is it that pretty much nobody suggests this as an authentication option?

Edit to clarify:

Contrast this with using transport security with certificates where you have to send the username and password with every request as part of the ClientCredentials.

If message level security provides confidentiality, integrity and authentication, then why is using a certificate a better option? What is the downside of passing the credentials as part of the encrypted body as opposed to passing it with ClientCredentials?

Comment: I am interested in finding out which option you went with?

Answer (score 4):

Passing the password with every request make attacks, where someone manages to read what is transmitted. If they get the password, they can log in at every time they want. They can even change the password, if they want. With a session-ID, they can only hijack a session, as long as it is active (and won't get access to better protected areas, like changing password areas, where you'll have to reconfirm by supplying the password again). To counteract a stolen password, you'll have to change your password (and remember the new one). To counteract a hijacked session ID you'll just have to end the session. You never remembered the session-ID anyway. Also, the password need's to be stored somewhere in the client application all the time, if you send it again and again. That's one more place where attackers could get the password from.

Hijacked passwords are actually worse, since often the same password is used for several different applications.

In addtion to all of that, you'd often use an extra slow algorithm to hash the password (that makes it harder to *guess* a password, since you'll have to wait. You'd probably want to add something like limited tries on a password per time unit, to exclude dictionary attacks. That doesn't really mix well with your idea.

I'd say overall it is a bad idea, to send your password all the time, independent or the framework used, it's more a principle for client/server applications. And since there are technics like sessions with IDs, why not use them. It's not more complicated than verifying the password all the time.

Comment: How can they get the hashed password if it's encrypted in the message body? As for someone trying to use a dictionary to decipher a password, isn't this a problem for every authentication method? "there are technics like sessions with IDs" Can you point to a page with an example?

Comment: @manuel Only if they read the body -- but that can often happen for various reasons. If it happens, I explained why it's worse with the password than with a session-ID. You should use the password as seldom as possible and not without the user knowing you do so (users should have control over when the password is used. If possible don't store it). For the principle you could start here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_ID -- there should be tons of sites out there, it's used in practically every web-site you can log in to.

Comment: It's still not clear what the pattern you're suggesting is. Is it that for every call to the service, if the session is not alive then an error is thrown, then catch the error, send the username/password, and make the call again?

Comment: @manuel I'm not to sure about your specific service since I neither know wcf nor your application. But the pattern I mean would be: first call to app: do login with username/password, answer is the sessionID (creates the session). Then do many calls doing your work, given the ID to every call. Last: logout, end session on server (making ID invalid). Of course that does only really make sence if you do make several calls in a short time period. It is a normal way to realise sessions over a protocol that does not support them (like http)

Comment: Not to be rude but this question is specific to WCF.

Comment: @manuel still I think the concept might be helpful to you, since keeping transmissions of the password few is normally a good principle when concerning security. Look at what mihai posted, he seems to have more insight into the specifics

Answer (score 2):

@kratenko is right, sending the password with each message is not such a good approach, though I agree with you, getting that password out of the encrypted message is not an easy thing to do. What you can do is use a double security on your WCF communication, meaning message security plus transport security (SSL). Here is an link which explains how you can achieve it: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article891-6-steps-to-implement-dual-security-on-wcf-using-user-name-ssl.aspx.

You still have other options, such as: send your user credentials on a secured channel (SSL) only once and based on the success of user authentication generate a token which you send back to the client. In this scenario on any further request the client has to provide that token in a custom header. At service level you can persist the generated token on high performance cache storage system such as Couchbase, so on every incoming request you will compare the token provided by the client with the one from your cache. In this way you cans till maintain you service stateless. If you do no like this idea then you can choose to use STS (security token service).

Comment: I understand your point about sessions and that a hijacked session is likely to be less damaging than a hijacked password hash. What nags me is why does every example of WCF username/password authentication out there uses the pattern of sending the username and password with the client credentials on every call? My guess is that implementing a session pattern would require either doing two trips to the server (one to check if the session is alive plus the call) or doing the call and checking to see if the server returns a session expired error.

Comment: Message security provides security for end-to-end communication. This means that it doesn't matters how many intermediaries are involved in message transmission. Also message security is based on industry standards which are addressing interoperability and common attacks (e.g.: DOS). Usually message security it is used in internet application. Note that for chatty applications message security adds an overhead due to the encryption of each message.

Comment: Transport security on the other hand it encrypts the entire channel communication. The main characteristics of transport security are: integrity, privacy and authentication. You also have to option to use Mixed transfer security which is a combination of both message security and transport security, but it comes with a downside, it is secured only in point-to-point communication (due to transfer security).

Comment: And if you really want to send your messages with an entire nuke bunker you can opt for both security options ( (that DUAL thingy) but that adds a big overhead having to encrypt the channel and also each message. The token concept about which I have mentioned in the answer has nothing to do with a session. Check the STS (security token service) concept. Note that it doesn't requires two requests at all. The only thing you have to do in a particular way is to get the token based on user name and password (authentication).